# Getting 403 error on ajax infinite loading script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Following recomendations on my previous question, I decided to implement an infinite loading script to my page. However, when it script triggers, I get a 403 - forbidden error. This is my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>";
    var page = 2;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            var data = {
                'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                'page': page,
                'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $('.main').append(response);
                page++;
            });
        }
    });

});
```

And this is in my functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nonpriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');

    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'spell',
        'posts_per_page' => '30',
        'paged' => $paged
    ];

    $my_posts = new WP_Query ($args);

    while($my_posts->have_posts()) {

        //the content goes here

    }

    wp_die();

}
```

I have double checked and everything seems fine, but I keep getting 403 errors. The initial query, before the script, goes through without any problems. The only third party plugin I have installed is Advanced Custom Fields.

EDIT: This is the console log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial and error, I still don't know what was causing the 403, or how to fix it, but I decided to change gears and found another solution for the infinite scroll, as describe in [this post](https://www.billerickson.net/infinite-scroll-in-wordpress/). At first, I was getting a 500 internal server error, but after some more trial and error, I pinpointed  the problem to a function that was being called from an included php file. I included that function's contents within the body of the code, and it now works.